# Cannot access global variable from JQuery on() method in Angular

Tags: jquery, angular

I am attempting to change the variable "currSideNavId" inside the jQuery on() method using Angular6. The current code below gives me TS error:

> [ts] Cannot find name 'currSideNavId'. [2304]

I am not sure how I can go about changing the global variable in this jQuery method. Thank you.

```
export class TimelineCreatorComponent implements OnInit {
    currSideNavId: number;

    ngOnInit (){
       this.timeline.on('select', function (properties) {
         console.log('selected items: ' + properties.items);
         currSideNavId = properties.items;

       });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can define the callback as an arrow function: `(properties) => { this.currSideNavId = properties.items; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the one way of doing.

```
export class TimelineCreatorComponent implements OnInit {
    currSideNavId: number;
    let me = this;
    ngOnInit (){
       this.timeline.on('select', function (properties) {
         console.log('selected items: ' + properties.items);
         me.currSideNavId = properties.items;

       });
    }
}
```